# Combining Menu and Tab

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using this "Tab layout and Listview" from http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/android-combining-tab-layout-and-list-view/ and "Android Menus" from http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/.
I merge them together, yet it doesn't work. The tab works, but not for the menu.
Here are my codes.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class optionMenuActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    // Initiating Menu XML file (menu.xml)
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Event Handling for Individual menu item selected
     * Identify single menu item by it's id
     * */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        Intent myList = new Intent();
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.menu_login:
            // Single menu item is selected do something
            // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
         //   Toast.makeText(optionMenuActivity.this, "Bookmark is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            myList = new Intent(optionMenuActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(myList);
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_save:
            Toast.makeText(optionMenuActivity.this, "Save is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_search:
            Toast.makeText(optionMenuActivity.this, "Search is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_share:
            Toast.makeText(optionMenuActivity.this, "Share is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_delete:
            Toast.makeText(optionMenuActivity.this, "Delete is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_quit:
         //   Toast.makeText(optionMenuActivity.this, "Preferences is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
           // return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }   

}
```

The main from "Tab layout"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And this is my menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Single menu item
         Set id, icon and Title for each menu item
    -->
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_login"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_bookmark"
          android:title="Login" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_save"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_save"
          android:title="Save" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_search"
          android:title="Search" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_share"
          android:title="Share" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_delete"
          android:title="Delete" /> 

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_quit"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_preferences"
          android:title="Quit" />
</menu>
```

And lastly, my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".WorkDroid5"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Inbox Activity -->
        <activity android:name=".AnnouncementActivity" />

        <!-- Outbox Activity -->
        <activity android:name=".HomeworkActivity" />

        <!-- Profile Activity -->
        <activity android:name=".TimetableActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".tt_Friday" />
        <activity android:name=".ttFinalDetails" />
        <activity android:name=".TimetableAdapter" />
        <activity android:name=".tt_Thursday" />
        <activity android:name=".tt_Monday" />
        <activity android:name=".tt_Tuesday" />
        <activity android:name=".tt_Wednesday" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="Register New Account" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="Login to your Account" >
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".optionMenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.example.OPTIONMENUACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

    <!-- Internet Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance for anyone's help (':

Comment: What do you mean by _"The tab works, but not for the menu"_? In what way it doesn't work: causing a crash, not showing, behaving incorrectly?

Comment: The tab is able to work normally. But not for the "menu". When I press the option button on my phone, it doesn't show the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

you pass `R.layout.menu` to `MenuInflater.inflate(..)` method, but it should be `R.menu.menu`. Move your `menu.xml` file from `res/layout` dir to `res/menu` dir.

Comment: Nope. Still doesn't work. Anyway, I've did the project with "R.layout.menu" before and it work. But not for now.

Comment: Don't you have `res/layout/menu.xml` file left?

Comment: Do you mean the previous working project or the current working one?

Comment: I mean the project, which you're testing. There should be one `menu.xml` file in `res/menu/` dir and no `res/layout/menu.xml` file left

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problem with TabHost. By default, Android creates an options menu for the parent activity, i.e. TabHost in your case. The child tab does not receive the `OnCreateOptionsMenu` event. Therefore, your menu is not being created.

Put the option menu creation/handling code in the activity extending TabActivity. You can change the preference menu content by checking which tab is currently selected by checking `getTabHost.getCurrentTab` or `getTabHost.getCurrentTabTag` and inflating appropriate menu.