# How to add Menu option in Activity from TabHost

Tags: android, menu, android-tabhost

I have a `TabHost` inside which there are 5 `Activities`.
My problem is if I am adding Menu Option on Actionbar from each Activity, it is not displaying on `ActionBar`.

If I add `Menu Option` from `TabHost` Activity, it is getting displayed on `ActionBar`.

But I want to add different action for each `Activity` when `Menu Option` is clicked.

Please help me how can I achieve it ??

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use `TabHost` `onTabChangedListener`.

```
    tabhost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            switch (tabId) {
                case "tab1":
                    //do stuff
                    break;

                 ...etc    
            }
        }
    });
```

This will keep track of which tab is clicked, and you can manually swap the action there.

**Edit** To expand on this a little more: you change the action (or `onClickListener` if you're using a custom action bar) for your menu button here. To all appearances, nothing changes upon each tab click, just the action that `MenuOptions` will perform. Some messy code that probably needs to be optimized; you'll have to do that yourself:

```
tabhost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        switch (tabId) {
            case "tab1":
                activity = "tab1";
                break;
            case "tab2":
                activity = "tab2";
                break;
            //etc
        }
    }
});
```

and then lower in the parent TabHost activity, you have this to respond to menu button presses:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        //this handles actions for your custom button
        case R.id.menu_options:
            //we further customize it here by listening to the value of "activity" and performing actions based on that
            switch (activity) {
                case "tab1":
                    //place your actual menu action here
                    break;
                case "tab2":
                    break;
                //etc
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Edit2**: Browsing some on StackOverflow gives [Can I have different menu for each tab of TabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618803/can-i-have-different-menu-for-each-tab-of-tabhost), which is similar but not quite the same since they want different menus, not same menu different actions. Might be worth a look, though.

Comment: you didn't get my question , I want to perform action from menu option from each activity not on TabHost's tab changed

Comment: I'm a bit confused. From your question, I thought you were asking how to set a different menu option for each activity? Like, the SAME button in the menu, but DIFFERENT actions depending on which tab is selected. In which case, `onTabChangedListener` lets you know the selected tab and you can tweak actions based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Hi following answer from  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884018/combining-menu-and-tab), I came to know that I can't create option from each Activity inside TabHost.

I used below code in `onOptionsItemSelected` method of My TabHost activity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.next) {

        Activity MyActivity = this.getCurrentActivity();

        if (Activity1.class.isInstance(MyActivity) == true) {

            ((Activity1) MyActivity).next();
        }
        if (Activity2.class.isInstance(MyActivity) == true) {

            ((Activity2) MyActivity).next();
        }
        if (Activity3.class.isInstance(MyActivity) == true) {

            ((Activity3) MyActivity).next();
        }
        if (DocumentsActivity.class.isInstance(MyActivity) == true) {
            //((DemoGraphicActivity) MyActivity).init();
            ((DocumentsActivity) MyActivity).next();
        }
        if (Activity4.class.isInstance(MyActivity) == true) {

            ((Activity4) MyActivity).next();
        }

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

and it worked like charm...

cheers....